# Put second display to sleep

Tags: display, thunderbolt-display

I just got a second display for my iMac and am wondering if there is a way to put the second one to sleep without putting both displays to sleep. I occasionally use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> to put both of them to sleep but if I'm watching a movie on one, it would be nice if I could make the other go dark without having to unplug it. That causes all my windows to get all screwed up. If not, I guess turning down the brightness all the way sort of works.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DisableMonitor](https://github.com/Eun/DisableMonitor). It is a tool that allows you to change the resolution of a monitor and/or enable and disable it. It works with multiple displays, and it should fix your problem.

Comment: That doesn't quite do it. I'm not sure if its a bug or what but he monitor is still on, just not useable. It shows its normal background (which is different from my iMac  display wallpaper) and moves all the windows I had open there to the iMac. I was hoping for something that could just put that one display to sleep and not rearrange everything.